# Eclipse refresh current file in editor

Tags: eclipse, caching, refresh

Is there a keyboard shortcut or menu item that refreshes the (cached) file in the current editorView?

I ask this, because I discovered a bug in Eclipse/RSE with a remote project. When you use F3 (Open declaration) to open a method in another file, it doesn't refresh that file, but opens it from the workspace-cache.
This is a real PITA, since we work with multiple developers on the same remote project. For now we should refresh the other file.

Kind regards, Johan Velthuis

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse there are also options "Refresh using native hooks or polling" and "Refresh on access".

[image: Eclipse: Preferences > General > Workspace]

Preferences > General > Workspace

I'm not using those, but it may be what you want.

On the other hand I do not know, what is added value to use remote project over some version system, but that's probably not your choice...

Comment: Thank for taking the time for an answer. But actually it doesn't. The 'Refresh using native hooks' only refreshes if the file changed on the computer, not for the server. The 'Refresh on access' works when you open a file from the Remote Systems Explorer, but not when one uses the 'Open declaration'.